# Filling HTML form from Node.js server

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping

I want to fill an HTML form's input fields, submit and retrieve the body of the page. I found a module called [form-scraper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-scraper) but my code gives me this error:

> Cannot read property 'get' of undefined at Function.get (/Users/.../node_modules/promisified-request/promisified-request.js:21:69)

```
var pRequest = require("promisified-request").create();
var fScraper = require("form-scraper");

var formStructure = fScraper.fetchForm("#mc-embedded-subscribe-form", "http://cats.com/", pRequest);

var loginDetails = {"EMAIL": "test@test.test"};

fScraper.submitForm(loginDetails, fScraper.provideForm(formStructure), pRequest).then(function(response) {
    console.log(response.body);
});
```

Any help or suggestions on how to go about it differentially appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know the code you have given is same as the example [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-scraper#example). But the example is a little incorrect. You'll have to pass a `request` to the `create` method.

Try this:

```
var request = require("request")
var pRequest = require("promisified-request").create(request);
var fScraper = require("form-scraper");

var formStructure = fScraper.fetchForm("#mc-embedded-subscribe-form", "http://cats.com/", pRequest);

var loginDetails = {"EMAIL": "test@test.test"};

fScraper.submitForm(loginDetails, fScraper.provideForm(formStructure), pRequest).then(function(response) {
    console.log(response.body);
});
```

And you don't need to install `"request"` package as it's already a dependency and thus is already installed